# Numeric error for zeros in seq [R]?

Tags: r

Why does an exact sequence that's supposed to traverse `0` have some small float instead? For instance, `seq(-0.6, 0.6, by = 0.2)` returns

`[1] -6.000000e-01 -4.000000e-01 -2.000000e-01  1.110223e-16  2.000000e-01
[6]  4.000000e-01  6.000000e-01`.

This doesn't always happen, either (`by = 0.3` with the same `from` and `to` is fine).

What is going on, and how do I prevent it from happening?